# finishTransaction: isn't removing the transaction from queue...

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have several non-consumable inApps.

The payment is done once (correctly: SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased), then the download of the inApp is correctly done (and finished) and finnaly I call

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

however the transactions remain in the queue... why? aren't they supposed to be removed? also the following isn't being called:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue removedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

I've also tried to implement in my finishtransaction method:

```
for (SKPaymentTransaction *aTransaction in [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions])
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:aTransaction];
}
```

(in case the transaction object i was trying to finish wasn't the correct one, but this also fails to remove the transactions - well most of the times, sometimes it does remove but the behaviour is inconsistent, I can't figure out why they are removed the few times they are actually removed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question, it appears that you are trying to download something when purchase completes. In this case, you should probably call finishTransaction before the download starts.

Comment: that was exactly my "workaround". Or is this the proper way? Documentation says to call finishtransaction AFTER the product has been delivered to the user. Calling it right away is working way better for me though

Comment: You should "remember" that the product has been purchased and not yet downloaded, and then call finish transaction. On a background thread, download content for any purchased product that has not yet been downloaded. The reason is, your app can be closed when it's downloading 3rd out of 5th product. Resuming the download is important since it's tied to a financial transaction

Comment: @Mugunth I am using your MSStoreKit and have had this problem with a simple non-consumable where a flag is set. Does MSStoreKit make any provision for this problem of transactions not being finished and removed from the queue? I have seen a suggestion to use dispatch_async around the call to failedTransactions, but I'm not sure if that is the way to go. I'd love to see MSStoreKit updated to handle this.

Comment: This is wrong. Apple docs ( https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW10 ) clearly state that you should call finishTransaction AFTER the associated product is downloaded

Comment: @xfze (and Mugunth) Could it be that the problem with getting all transactions is because of [this line in Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506026-transactions): "The value of this property [-transactions] is undefined when there are no observers attached to the payment queue."