# `startDownloads` not working on restored transaction. `updatedDownloads` not called

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, storekit, skpaymenttransaction, iap-hosted-content

I have an issue with the restoration of hosted in-app purchase content. Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't work at all. My users are also reporting this issue.

I had a hard time trying to replicate it, but I managed to run into a situation when it happens.

Right now whenever I run the app on my Mac from Xcode, my store delegate is notified about two pending restoration transactions in the queue shortly after launch. And the following function is being called:

```
func provideContent(_ transaction:SKPaymentTransaction) {
    if transaction.downloads.count > 0 {
        GLXLogger.shared.addGeneralLog(format: "[STORE] starting download")
        SKPaymentQueue.default().start(transaction.downloads)
    }
```

I see the log message `[STORE] starting download` so I know that this code is executed. And then nothing happens. `updatedDownloads` is not called. I have verified that `finishTransaction` is also not called so this cannot possibly be interrupting normal execution.

I am basically out of ideas as to what could be causing this problem. I know that this scenario has two pending restoration transactions, but I see no reason why it should lead to such a failure. It corresponds to what I see in the logs of some of my users. For them `SKPaymentQueue.default().start(transaction.downloads)` is called followed by nothing happening.

I would appreciate if you could help me debug this by at least throwing some ideas as to what you think could be causing such weird behaviour.

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861657/finishtransaction-isnt-removing-the-transaction-from-queue?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Kamran firstly, I do not see how this is related to the fact that downloads are not starting. Secondly, the answer you cited is wrong. You should NOT call finishTransaction until the associated download is complete. This is taken from Apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW10

Comment: Are you setting the `SKProductsRequestDelegate` ?

Comment: @user1046037 I do, though it is not relevant for this question. `SKProductsRequestDelegate` is responsible for processing the list of available IAPs. You probably meant `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` ;)

Comment: What’s happening on the network side of things? Is something else interfering with your app’s request?

Comment: @Mrwerdo there are no other network requests which my app is sending

Comment: What happens when you change which network your computer is on? Have you tried creating a sample project which illustrates the problem? Another option is [requesting support from an engineering](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical). It’s worth keeping your options open.